# Calculate exponentiation of real numbers by only using +, -, * and / as operators

Tags: java, math, exponentiation

I am trying to build an exponentiation function for real numbers where I cannot use the Math library in Java. The only operators I am allowed to use are +, -, * and /. No sqrt or log or any other function other than these 4 operators. I am able to do it for a whole number since it is pretty easy but cannot figure out how to for real numbers...
Both the base and exponent can be real numbers

```
public static void power(){

        System.out.println("\nPower function... ");
        System.out.println("Enter the base: ");
        long base = scan.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Enter the exponent: ");
        long exp = scan.nextLong();
        System.out.println("Calculating " + base + "^" + exp + "...");

        long answer = 1;
        while(exp != 0) {
            answer *= base;
            exp--;
        }
        System.out.println(answer); 
}
```

Comment: so your problem is if the exp is something like" 3,14"?

Comment: Do you need it to work only for real number bases or real number exponents as well?

Comment: What you have here is a maths question. Maybe you should ask it on a maths website.

Comment: yes, any exponent that is a real number, and the base can also be a real number

Comment: if you are able to calculate the SQRT (use something like Newton  method) you can rewrite the exp as a/b, and so calculate base^a and then calculate the b-th root of that number

Comment: If you don't know that the exponent is an integer, that makes it an extremely hard function to write.  However, it sounds like you are basically trying to re-create Java's `Math.pow` method in your own code.  This has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38236538/whats-the-algorithm-behind-math-pow-in-java)

Comment: You solution also does not work with negative exponentiation.

Comment: see [Power by squaring for negative exponents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) and just pick a method. Either log/exp (which you must implement) or power by squaring for integer part *  power by sqrting for fractional part of exponent.